# 401 Unauthorized - Chrome extension with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create login functionality in chrome extension using angular, but its always giving me **401 UNAUTHORIZED** error, below is my code:

```
angular.module('chrome-extension')
.controller('LoginController',[ '$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.loginUser = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'appurl',
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.user)
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('Success');
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Error');
        });
    }
}]);
```

Here is request header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:167
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:sessionid=a8y239cyid0sosopmmw2nql6hxbc; csrftoken=DCRJcxonsnLCDHZEkcGewGM6WcpH; _ga=GA1.2.181813245.1461809
Host:test.example.com
Origin:chrome-extension://ooejphiapldnooopoohjcfggimji
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: This question is pointless, we know nothing about your end service.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use OAuth 2.0 for authentication within extensions. Never pass the username/password because an attacker can simply steal such information.

An example from Chromium regarding OAuth in extensions is *[Tutorial: OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth)*.

Additionally, there's an experimental API available for OAuth 2.0, which is supposed to make the whole process a little easier. There's a comprehensive blog post, *[OAuth 2.0 from Chrome Extensions](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions)*.